# Is it okay to implement an MVC application with an RFID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, rfid

The RFID was used for logging purposes, I've seen some conflict there, but despite of that is it possible to develop a web app using MVC with a RFID? Any articles? Code source or even examples you could suggest?

Comment: by the way I was thinking of using ASP.NET MVC4 on this stuff.